# Why does "android resource linking failed error"?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

```
Android resource linking failed
com.example.menuandflexbox.app-mergeDebugResources-35:/layout/activity_signup.xml:195: error: resource drawable/baseline_calendar_month_24 (aka com.example.menuandflexbox:drawable/baseline_calendar_month_24) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Find solution to this problem.

Comment: Provide code snippets in order to understand question more.

Comment: You may not generated drawable file. Generate from `File->New->Vector Asset`